# How to prevent multiple ajax requests when multiple browser windows are open

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have been working on having a instant messaging system on a website(kind of like Facebook and Gmail). I have javascript poll the server for new messages.

If the user has multiple instances of the site open is there any way to prevent each one from making requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign each "new" load of the page with a UUID, and drop requests from all UUIDs that are not the most recent one for user. You need to send the UUID back in each request. If you want to get advanced, you can have the JavaScript on the page check the response to see if the server says it's an old UUID, and that it should stop making the requests.

Comment: Beat me to posting the same basic idea. Good on you.

Answer (score 3):

Register each connection with a GUID generated on the fly in the browser. Check the GUID and the username pair to see which page was owner last. On page load, declare yourself a new window and that you're taking ownership. Sort of `PageJustLoadedMakeMeOwner(myGuid, username)`

Then have that GUID targeted frame update the server regularly for it's ownerness of the page.

If it stops updating the server, then have rules in the server that allow the next page to contact to take ownership of for that username.

Have pages that have lost ownership self-demote to only accessing once a minute or so.

The response to check if a given page is owner of that username is really fast. Takes almost no time to do, as far as the client is aware. So the AJAX there doesn't really restrict you.

Sort of a `AmIOwner(username, myGuid)` check (probably do this every five seconds or so). If true, then do the thing that you want to happen. If false, then poll to see if the owner of the page is vacant. If true, then take ownership. If false, then poll again in xx amount of seconds to see if the owner is vacant.

Does that make any sort of sense?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something for multiple instances in the same browser, but there's nothing you can do if the user has multiple browsers. (Granted, not that common scenario)

If you still want to give it a try, probably the easiest way would be to keep a timestamp of the last request in a cookie and make new request only upon a certain threshold. You still might run a small race until the multiple instance s settle down, but if you use fuzzy time period for the polls, the instances should settle down pretty quickly to a stable state where one of the instances makes the call and the others reuse the result from the last call.

The main advantage of that approach is that the requests can be made by any of the instances, so you don't have to worry about negotiating a "primary" instance that makes the calls and figuring a fallback algorithm if the user closes the "primary" one. The main drawback is that since it's a fuzzy timing based algorithm, it does not fully eliminate the race conditions and occasionally you'll have two instances make the requests. You'll have to fine tune the timing a bit, to minimize that case, but you can't fully prevent it.